# Detecting the position of the mouse click

Tags: java, calendar

Okay so I finally found it out!! now I just need help on one more thing. I need to detect where I click, see if it's in the Calendar and then detect which box was click on.
if you could help me that would be AMAZING!!!

Here's my code!:

```
package drawing;

import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
public class Drawing_something extends JPanel{
    //private JLabel statusBar;
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    int[] calender_squares = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};

    String[] Month = {"January", "February", "March", "April","May","June","July",
            "August","September","October","November","December"};

    String[] Days = {"Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"};

    int g = 0, i = 0, fillRectx = 250, fillRecty = 150, fillRectWidth = 99, fillRectHeight = 99;

    int x = 0, y = 0;
    static int year = 2014;

    boolean currentDate = true, anotherDay = false, itsJune = true;

    String date = "";

    private int calculateBlankDays(int month){
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.set(year, month, 1);
        return cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) - 1;
    }

    private static int getDaysInMonth(int month){
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.set(year, month, 1);
        return cal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    }

//  private int calculateCurrentDay(int month){
//      Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
//      cal.set(year, month, 10);
//      return cal.get(Calendar.DATE);
//  }
//  
    private int currentMonth(int month){
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MONTH);
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM");
        return Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MONTH);
    }

    private String getDateTime(){
        DateFormat dateformat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        Date date = new Date();
        return dateformat.format(date);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics c){

        super.paintComponent(c);
        this.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) c;
        Calendar C = Calendar.getInstance();
        int currentDay = C.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR);
        int blankDays = calculateBlankDays(i);
        int WIDTH = 55 + (blankDays * 100); 
        int HEIGHT = 65;
        int currentDayOfTheYear = C.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR);


        if (currentDate){
            i = currentMonth(i);
            currentDate = false;
        }

        // Drawing the squares on the canvas
        for (@SuppressWarnings("unused") int in: calender_squares) {
            for (int counter = 0; counter < 7; counter++){
                c.drawRect(50, 50, 25, 25);
                c.drawRect(50, 50, 700, 600);
                c.copyArea(50, 50, 600, 500, 100, 0);
                c.copyArea(50, 50, 700, 500, 0, 100);
            }
        }
        // Setting the transparency of the rectangle highlighting the day
        g2d.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, 0.3f));
        g2d.setColor(Color.CYAN);
        g2d.fillRect(currentDay + 161, currentDay - 39, 98, 98);
        g2d.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, 1.0f));
        c.setColor(Color.BLACK);

        if (anotherDay){
            fillRectx += 100;
            anotherDay = false;
            if (fillRectx > 650){
                fillRectx = 50;
                fillRecty += 100;
                anotherDay = false;
            }
        }

        // setting the correct days in the month
        for (int date = 1; date <= getDaysInMonth(i); date++){
            String s = String.valueOf(date);
            c.drawString(s, WIDTH, HEIGHT);

            if (WIDTH > 555){
                WIDTH = 55;
                HEIGHT += 100;
            } else {
                WIDTH += 100;
            }
        }
        if (g == 1){
            g2d.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, 0.6f));
            g2d.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
            g2d.fillRect(x, y, 100, 100);
            g2d.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, 1.0f));
            c.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        }
        // Drawing and Redrawing every month when buttons are pressed
        if (i >= 12){
            i = 0;
            year = year + 1;
        } else if (i < 0){
            i = 11;
            year = year - 1;
        }

        c.setFont(new Font("default", Font.BOLD, 18));
        c.drawString("Sunday", 65, 45);
        c.drawString("Monday", 165, 45);
        c.drawString("Tuesday", 265, 45);
        c.drawString("Wednesday", 350, 45);
        c.drawString("Thursday", 465, 45);
        c.drawString("Friday", 565, 45);
        c.drawString("Saturday", 665, 45);

        c.setFont(new Font("default", Font.BOLD, 40));
        c.drawString(Month[i], 320, 28);
        repaint();

        c.setFont(new Font("default", Font.BOLD, 40));
        c.drawString(String.valueOf(year), 800, 45);


    }

    //defining the buttons to change the months
    public Drawing_something(){
        setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        JButton N = new JButton("NEXT");

        JButton B = new JButton("BACK");

        JButton Test = new JButton("Test Button");

        JPanel P = new JPanel();

        JPanel L = new JPanel();
        //mouse clicking
        JPanel mousepanel = new JPanel();
        mousepanel.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
        //statusBar = new JLabel("default");

        P.add(B);
        P.add(N);
        P.add(Test);

        add(P, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        add(L, BorderLayout.EAST);
        //add(statusBar, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(mousepanel);

        B.addActionListener(new HandlerClass());
        N.addActionListener(new NextClass());
        Test.addActionListener(new TestClass());
        mousepanel.addMouseListener(new MouseClick());
    }

    // BACK BUTTON
    public class HandlerClass implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            i -= 1;
            itsJune = false;
        }
    }

    // NEXT BUTTON
    public class NextClass implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            i += 1;
            itsJune = false;
        }
    }

    // TEST BUTTON
    public class TestClass implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            anotherDay = true;
        }
    }

    //Mouse Click Listener
    public class MouseClick implements MouseListener{
        // Changing the statusBar(JLabel) to the destination of the click.
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            x = e.getX();
            y = e.getY();
            //System.out.println("Your click is now known");
            g = 1;
        }

        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    }
        // Opening the Frame
        public static void main(String[] args){
            JFrame mainFrame = new JFrame("Calender");
            mainFrame.add(new Drawing_something());
            mainFrame.setSize(950, 780);
            mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            mainFrame.setVisible(true);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have a `MousListener` on the top level `JPanel`, which is packed with lots of buttons.  As the focus of the click will travel with the mouse, would you verify that your clicks are landing on the JPanel and not on one of the interior sub-components?

If so, perhaps one of your buttons is handling the mouse click.

Comment: Okay, I don't really understand on what you are saying. but I added "add(mousepanel)" where all the other "add"'s are. and it's making my whole screen gray. Help?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you never added the mousepanel to neither the main JPanel nor any other JPanel. Maybe do:

```
add(mousepanel); // With some kind of BorderLayout
```

Comment: yes, I have just done that. and it makes my calendar all grey and doesn't work. and I wound't like a panel, I'd like to click anywhere on the window of my program

Comment: Have you tried to just add the mouselistener to the main JPanel? As in addMouseListener(new MouseClick());?

Comment: The main one, not the one you create in the constructor @DarkStar123

Answer (score 0):

`MouseClick` should extend `MouseAdapter` and override `mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)` instead of implementing `MouseListener` and having a whole bunch of unused methods.

Anyway, just call `addMouseListener(new MouseClick());` in the constructor. You don't need `MousePanel`